# Defining preprocessor directives gives unknown identifier while compilation

Tags: c

I am using the following macro definition in my C program, however, after compilation, it is giving me error that macro names should be identifier. Can anybody tell me what mistake I am doing while defining macro?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define a0 0
#define x1 1
#define a1 2
#define x0 3
#define x0a1 4
#define b0 5
#define b1 6
#define y0 7
#define y1 8
#define y0b1 9
#define c0 10
#define z1 11
#define c1 12
#define b1 13
#define z0 14

#define 1R0 0
#define 1B0 1
#define 1W0 2

#define 2R0 3
#define 2B0 4
#define 2W0 5

#define 3R0 6
#define 3B0 7
#define 3W0 8

#define Running 0
#define Blocked 1
#define Waiting 2
```

Comment: Macro identifiers (names) can't begin with digits.

Comment: `1R0`...not an identifier

Comment: Even the Stackoverflow C syntax colorizer knows that macro identifiers can't start with a digit... Just look at what you provided: proper identifiers are black or blue when capitalized, those starting with digits are red.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define 2R0 3
```

Identifiers must start with either a letter or underscore, digits are not allowed.